# Jquery DatePicker Not Hiding After PopUp Close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker

In Yii I have a modal popup using CJuiDialog which is a wrapper for jquery's dialog. In this dialog I have a CJuiDatPicker which is a wrapper for jquery's datepicker.

If I close the dialog and then open a new dialog a datepicker opens and stays visible. If I close the 2nd dialog, the datepicker stays open. If I open a 3rd dialog, a 2nd datepicker opens and stays open even after closing the dialog.

How can I force the datepicker to close? Or, possibly more correctly when the dialog is opened for a 2nd or more time, how can I prevent it from opening a previous datepicker?

Edit: Code for view listed below:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Add Purchase','#', 
array('onClick'=>'addTrans._addTrans_url="' . Yii::app()->createUrl('ortransaction/create',array('investment_id'=>$model->id,'type'=>OrTransaction::TYPE_BUY)) . '";{addTrans()};$("#dialogAddTrans").dialog("open");return false;'));?>

<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
'id'=>'dialogAddTrans',
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Add Purchase',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
    'modal'=>true,
),
));?>

<div class="divForAddTrans"></div>

<?php $this->endWidget();?>

<script type="text/javascript">
//this is the magic that loads the form correctly
function addTrans()
{
    //public proprety
    var _addTrans_url;

    <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
        'url'=>'js:addTrans._addTrans_url',
        'data'=>"js:$(this).serialize()",
        'type'=>'post',
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'success'=>"function(data)
        {
            if(data.status =='failure')
            {
                $('#dialogAddTrans div.divForAddTrans').html(data.div);
                //here is the trick: on submit->once again, call this function
                $('#dialogAddTrans div.divForAddTrans form').submit(function(){addTrans(); return false;});
            }else{
                $('#dialogAddTrans div.divForAddTrans').html(data.div);
                setTimeout(\"$('#dialogAddTrans').dialog('close')\",3000);
            }
        } ",
    ))?>;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you put your code. you are not coding the datepicker within the dialog properly, so show us your entire view's code.

Comment: Just added the code from the view that deals with this

Comment: Okay, just determined that it works fine in firefox - but Chrome is the one giving the problems.

Answer (score 1):

you can destroy the dialog content before loading/opening the dialog and relod the contents again